# Excel - averaging an n amount of rows based on condition in prior column

Tags: excel, indexing

I have this table in excel:

```
Date        value
1/2/1970    100.00
1/5/1970     99.99
1/6/1970    100.37
1/7/1970    100.74
1/8/1970    101.26
1/9/1970    100.74
1/12/1970   100.79
1/13/1970   101.27
1/14/1970   101.95
1/15/1970   101.97
1/16/1970   101.76
1/19/1970   102.21
1/20/1970   102.70
1/21/1970   102.00
1/22/1970   101.46
1/23/1970   101.49
1/26/1970   100.97
1/27/1970   101.45
1/28/1970   101.70
1/29/1970   102.08
1/30/1970   102.19
2/2/1970    102.02
2/3/1970    101.85
```

These are values that I have daily, and I need to construct a sheet that takes a monthly index of the daily values, example below:

```
date        index
1/31/1970   some_index
2/28/1970   some_index
3/31/1970   some_index
4/30/1970   some_index
```

I could only get this far when it came to getting the index of 30 days:

```
=AVERAGE(INDEX(B:B,1+30*(ROW()-ROW($C$1))):INDEX(B:B,30*(ROW()-ROW($C$1)+1)))
```

I'm just not sure how to structure this in the most efficient, yet correct way possible. Not all months are the same amount of days, so I was hoping to check to get all the next n rows where the date starts with a "1" for example, sometimes certain days are also missing. I can't think of a catch all approach.

Comment: Why not AVERAGEIFS based on date?

Comment: Not familiar with it, what would it look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With 1/31/1970 in C1 try this,

```
=averageifs(daily!b:b, daily!a:a, "<="&c1, daily!a:a, ">="&eomonth(c1, -1)+1)
```

Comment: I adjusted the command to be 1 row down because of headers, but all this does is make every row in column C this: 1/0/1900

Comment: Command for reference:    =AVERAGEIFS(B:B,A:A, "<="&C2,A:A, ">="&EOMONTH(C2, -1)+1)

Comment: @Muffinman the `C1` was meant to be a static date,  Try changing both `C1` to `B2` make sure you format the column to general.

Comment: take a look at [this](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fa3qYKE85zTdLdDWIpbm1Ey2WlOBYbqSsrvYoZLPBr0/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

A PivotTable might be more convenient:

[image: SO48892108 example]